# What does the management system in RDBMS mean?

Tags: database, rdbms

When I hear someone mention any particular [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system), they generally refer to it as a database. What is intended by the term "management system"?

Comment: Just wondering, are you sure it's not content management system? Because a lot of times CMS' use RDBMS for their databases.  Just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 4):

A database is simply someplace to store data -- A file that you dump names & addresses into is technically a database.

A database management system includes all the other tools that make it easier to work with (manage) your data -- a query language, a way of defining structure, methods of indexing the data for faster access, etc.

Generally speaking you don't have a database without a management system these days.